# How to convert python code to format for graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz

I can't seem to find any sort of instructions on how to use graphviz. I have python webcrawler code which  outputs a list of websites, and I want to change the format of what is printed but don't know how to make it readable by graphviz. If anyone could point me in the right direction, offer any tips, or link me to any python ->graphviz tutorials or instructions, I would greatly appreciate it.

output when "www.google.com" is passed as an arg:

{'www.google.com': {'news.google.com', 'play.google.com', 'www.youtube.com', 'mail.google.com', 'maps.google.com', 'plus.google.com', 'drive.google.com', 'accounts.google.com'}}

Comment: I'm not sure how it needs to be edited to work with graphviz, that's part of my question. I'm having trouble finding anything helpful about how to use graphviz in the first place. But I edited the question to include sample output, good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't completely clear to me how you want to use GraphViz in this application. However, given a dictionary as you describe, you can produce a GraphViz script to draw it as follows:

```
gr = {'www.google.com': ['news.google.com', 'play.google.com', 'www.youtube.com',
      'mail.google.com', 'maps.google.com', 'plus.google.com',
      'drive.google.com','accounts.google.com']}

print ("digraph G {\nrankdir=LR;")
n = 0
lookup = {}
for root in gr.keys():
    if not (root in lookup):
        lookup[root] = n
        print ('n%d [label="%s"];' % (n,root))
        n += 1
    for leaf in gr[root]:
        if not (leaf in lookup):
            lookup[leaf] = n
            print ('n%d [label="%s"];' % (n,leaf))
            n += 1
        print ('n%d -> n%d;' % (lookup[root],lookup[leaf]))

print ("}")
```

When run through `dot`, the output from this Python script gives you:

[image]